# Include columns that are mandatory in the dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe below.

```
asd <- data.frame(a=c(1:10),b=c(11,20),c=(21:30),d=c(31:40),e=c(41,50),f=c(51,60))
```

Below are the 2 vectors which includes column names of asd

```
Column_list1 <- c("a","b","d")
Column_list2 <- c("c","e","f")
```

Below is the mandatory list of columns

```
mandatory_column <- c("a","b","d","e")
```

Now actually my question is when I try to run `asd[Column_list1]`, the result should throw an message. Because the mandatory columns should be `c("a","b","d","e")` and since `Column_list1` do not have "e", I need to print the message, "Please include column "e" as well". Is this something possible to achieve?

Expected output

```
asd[Column_list1]
Please include column "e" as well
```

```
asd[mandatory_column]
    a  b  d  e
1   1 11 31 41
2   2 20 32 50
3   3 11 33 41
4   4 20 34 50
5   5 11 35 41
6   6 20 36 50
7   7 11 37 41
8   8 20 38 50
9   9 11 39 41
10 10 20 40 50
```

Comment: `stopifnot( all(mandatory_column %in% colnames(asd)) )`?

Comment: Are you trying to write a function or something? Where do you want this check to take place?

Comment: I am writing a shiny app. So if I run asd[column_list1], it should a message " Please select column e as well"

Comment: @r2evans , I tried ````stopifnot(all(mandatory_column %in% Column_list1))```` and got this error
````Error: all(mandatory_column %in% Column_list1) is not TRUE````. Instead of this error, Can I have "Please select column e as well"

Comment: Wouldn't it be more convenient if you use something like `asd[union(mandatory_column, Column_list1)]`?

Comment: (1) *"writing a shiny app"* changes **everything** as far as errors and how to continue. That should be in your question, and you should add the [tag:shiny] tag. (2) Error message ... `if (!all(...)) stop(...)` works, but since you want shiny, then still more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mess with the class of your object `asd`, a S3 method comes to mind.

```
`[.special` <- function(x, i, ..., mandatory = mandatory_column){
  on.exit({
    cols_missing <- setdiff(mandatory, i)
    if(length(cols_missing) > 0){
      msg <- paste(sQuote(cols_missing), collapse = ", ")
      msg <- paste("Please include columns", msg)
      warning(msg)
    }
  })
  NextMethod(x, i, ...)
}


Column_list1 <- c("a","b","d")
Column_list2 <- c("c","e","f")
mandatory_column <- c("a","b","d","e")
```

The first call  still calls the `[.data.frame` method.

```
asd[Column_list1]
```

Now call the `[.special` method. It subsets the data and gives a warning.

```
class(asd) <- c("special", class(asd))
asd[Column_list1]
asd[Column_list2]
asd[mandatory_column]
```

Comment: This doesn't work with `asd[,Column_list1]`, where `i` is missing. Especially where `data.frame`, `data.table`, and `tbl_df` do not all agree on what `[1]` means, I wonder if this should be a little more robust to the presence of another argument.

Answer (score 1):

```r
mandatory_columns <- c("cyl", "disp", "gear", "quux")
stopifnot(all(mandatory_columns %in% colnames(mtcars)))
# Error: all(mandatory_columns %in% colnames(mtcars)) is not TRUE
```

Alternatively:

```r
missingfields <- setdiff(mandatory_columns, colnames(mtcars))
if (length(missingfields)) {
  stop("missing fields: ", paste(sQuote(missingfields), collapse = ", "))
}
# Error: missing fields: 'quux'


### with a subset of mtcars, demonstrating more missing columns:
missingfields <- setdiff(mandatory_columns, colnames(mtcars)[1:4])
if (length(missingfields)) {
  stop("missing fields: ", paste(sQuote(missingfields), collapse = ", "))
}
# Error: missing fields: 'gear', 'quux'
```

---

If you're using `shiny` and want validation/message without stopping the program, use `validate`, `need`, and `req`:

```r
  output$my_table <- renderTable({
    validate(need(req(all(mandatory_columns %in% names(mtcars))), "Missing columns"))
    asd[,mandatory_columns]
  })
```

Comment: Awesome @r2evans, it worked. Can i ask one last question, If there is no error, it should execute asd[Column_list1], meaning values in Column_list1 is present in Mandatory_column? Is it possible?

Comment: *"if there is no error, it should execute"* ... any code after the block with `stop` will continue running if the code does not stop. What am I missing?